# US Citizen living in UK with ILR, can I work remotely as freelancer for German company while residing in UK?

Tags: working-visas, germany, us-citizens, freelance, uk-citizenship

I am a US citizen and have Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK.  I am eligible to apply for citizenship now but I haven't yet.  Because of the pandemic I am living in London but I was offered a job to work remotely for a company based in Berlin.  Do I need a work permit even if it is just a short freelance job? If I do need a permit, which one do I need?

Would it be easier if I was a UK citizen?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indefinite leave to Remain (ILR) in the UK is also known as permanent residency.

With this type of permit then you are allowed to live and work in the UK, and you don't require any other permit or visa to work in the UK, either as an employee or self-employed.  You are subject to the law and statuary rules for establishing a business and your employment.

If you are performing the work in the UK, then the fact that you are working for a company in another country remotely does not make any difference for the UK authorities, so long as you pay your tax, social security contributions etc. and abide by all applicable laws etc.

More details here:
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/indefinite-leave-to-remain-in-the-uk